# How to connect to Cisco switch over SSH with Python Paramiko

Tags: python, cisco

I want to write a Python script for to create a connection to switch Cisco.
I have used Paramiko module of Python but it returns a connection error.

Code:

```
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.2', username='cisco',password='cisco')
```

It return this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicola/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/cisco.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.2', username='cisco',password='cisco')
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 751, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1509, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 250, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']
```

---

i have used the file of linux /home/$USER/.ssh/known_host.

this is errors

```
raise SSHException("not a valid {} private key file".format(tag))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid OPENSSH private key       
file
```

---

I have resolved the error of RSA key. Now python accept RSA key with this command

```
key=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(filename='/home/nicola`/.ssh/sg500.pem')`
```

But first I had to create an RSA vaild pem key file

```
ssh-keygen -f known_hosts -m pem
```

In known_hosts file was saved only RSA key of the device

Now i have another error when i run the command

```
client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.2',port=22,username='cisco',password='cisco',pkey=key)
```

the errors

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 416, in connect
    self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
  File "/home/nicola/PycharmProjects/cisco/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 824, in missing_host_key
    "Server {!r} not found in known_hosts".format(hostname)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server '192.168.1.2' not found in known_hosts
```

Comment: Looks like the switch only allows SSH connections using keys

Comment: i use a ssh connecction whit linux shell and cisco device allow it

Comment: how can i use paramiko with key?

Answer (score 0):

Try using your ssh key generated on your router after copying it to your computer.

```
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.2', key_filename=<your path to key>)
```